# Logic App : Create a zip file in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I am trying to create zip from a sharepoint folder which has multiple files. I am able to get the content of each file into an array ( as per diagram below) . But I am having challenges to pull the content from the array and create one zip file for all the files ("Create file" step).

[image]

Have anyone done something similar to this before?

regards,
Alan

Comment: An Azure function will do it for you, have you looked into using that approach?

Comment: The client only uses logic app, so I have to go with logic app

Comment: Azure functions are built into the Azure landscape, you extend your LogicApp using a function.  If they don't want to use functions then you're going to be limited at times.  Have you asked them?

Comment: Yeah ..we are going with azure function option. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I could able to achieve your requirement using a 3rd party connector called `Encodian` which has an action called `Add to Archive (ZIP)`.  Below is the flow that worked for me.

[image][image]

Firstly, I tried to retrieve the properties and the contents of each and every file from the folder that I'm trying to zip. Then I stored its details in below format into an array which will be passed through `Add to Archive (ZIP)` action and finally saved the results by `Create file` action of SharePoint connector.

```
{
  "fileContent": @{base64(body('Get_file_content'))},
  "fileName": @{body('Get_file_properties')?['{FilenameWithExtension}']}
}
```

**Here is the structure of my files in SharePoint**

[image]

***Before Compression***

[image]

***After Compression***

[image]

you can reproduce the same in your logic app using below code view

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Add_to_Archive_(ZIP)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "FinalOperation": true,
                        "documents": "@variables('Files')",
                        "encoding": "UTF8",
                        "encryption": "ZipCrypto",
                        "outputFilename": "ZipFolder.zip"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['encodiandocumentmanager']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/api/v1/Core/AddToZip"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Create_file": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": "@base64ToBinary(body('Add_to_Archive_(ZIP)')?['FileContent'])",
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sharepointonline']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('h<YOUR-SITE-URL>'))}/files",
                    "queries": {
                        "folderPath": "/Shared Documents",
                        "name": "@body('Add_to_Archive_(ZIP)')?['Filename']",
                        "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Add_to_Archive_(ZIP)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "contentTransfer": {
                        "transferMode": "Chunked"
                    }
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Condition": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Append_to_array_variable": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "Files",
                                    "value": {
                                        "fileContent": "@base64(body('Get_file_content'))",
                                        "fileName": "@body('Get_file_properties')?['{FilenameWithExtension}']"
                                    }
                                },
                                "runAfter": {
                                    "Get_file_content": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                            },
                            "Get_file_content": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "host": {
                                        "connection": {
                                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sharepointonline']['connectionId']"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "method": "get",
                                    "path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('<YOUR-SITE-URL>'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(body('Get_file_properties')?['{Identifier}'])}/content"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "ApiConnection"
                            }
                        },
                        "expression": {
                            "and": [
                                {
                                    "equals": [
                                        "@body('Get_file_properties')?['{IsFolder}']",
                                        false
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Get_file_properties": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "If"
                    },
                    "Get_file_properties": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sharepointonline']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "get",
                            "path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('<YOUR-SITE-URL>'))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('<->'))}/items/@{encodeURIComponent(items('For_each')?['ID'])}/getfileitem",
                            "queries": {
                                "view": "c5febd41-6227-4240-b023-0be5688aab0d"
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Get_files_(properties_only)')?['value']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_files_(properties_only)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Get_files_(properties_only)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sharepointonline']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('<YOUR-SITE-URL>'))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('<->'))}/getfileitems"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Files",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "encodiandocumentmanager": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<SUB - ID>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/encodiandocumentmanager",
                    "connectionName": "encodiandocumentmanager",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<SUB - ID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/encodiandocumentmanager"
                },
                "sharepointonline": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<SUB - ID>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sharepointonline",
                    "connectionName": "sharepointonline",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<SUB - ID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/sharepointonline"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```